# jQuery Validate not working on form loaded by Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, smoothstate.js

I have a form that I add with Ajax and use the jQuery Validate. I delegate associate with .on() but this does not attached to the form.

Not sure what I might have missed and there is very little details about using Validate.js with a dynamic form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("validate", "#contactForm", function() {
        $('#contactForm').validate({
          ....
        });                    // <- end '.validate()'
    });
});
```

Comment: [There is no such `"validate"` event as part of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events) that you can delegate with `.on()`.  You can only call `.validate()` immediately after loading the form's HTML.  Show the code that actually loads the form into the page.

Comment: The form is loaded through ajax as part of the smoothState.js Pjax plugin. It is just plain html. smoothState.js loads the entire <body> of the page with the form as part of that.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you.  You can only attach/call `.validate()` on a form that already exists in the DOM.  It cannot be delegated.

Comment: I added the [tag:smoothstate.js] tag to your post, but I think the smoothState plugin is a critical detail that should have been mentioned in the OP.  Thanks.

Comment: Since smoothState.js is more or less a pre-fetch ajax I though ajax was the important part. Fair point though, thanks

Comment: I have updated the question since as you mention the `"validate"` is not part of the `.on()` I have added `submit` instead as I would have thought it would work like the `click` event of a button

Comment: That is even worse!  That's the absolute most common mistake with using this plugin... the `.validate()` method is used ONE time for initializing the plugin.  It NEVER belongs inside of a `submit` or even a `click` handler.  You MUST only call `.validate()` on DOM ready... **in your case**, simply *after* the HTML is loaded by smoothState plugin.

Comment: I rolled back the question so that the answer makes sense to new readers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic premise of the question is flawed...

```
$("body").on("validate", ...
```

[There is no such "validate" event as part of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events) that you can delegate with `.on()`. You can only call the `.validate()` method immediately after loading the form's HTML, which initializes the plugin.

You can only attach/call `.validate()` onto a form that already exists in the DOM. In other words, it cannot be delegated.

---

[Referring to the documentation for the smoothState plugin](https://github.com/miguel-perez/jquery.smoothState.js#callback), there is an option called `callback` that is run *"after the new content has been injected into the page"*.

This is where you would have to call the `.validate()` method.

```
callback : function(url, $container, $content) { // <- fires AFTER page (form) is loaded
    $('#contactForm').validate({ // <- initializes the plugin on your form
        ....
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Using the .on() with click events is straight forward and I thought it would be the same with a form. It is obviously more complicated then that. The page that the form is only can also be loaded directly with the URL. Would you suggest having it with the $(document).ready and the smoothState.js callback?

Comment: @KeithPower, you do not need a DOM ready handler inside there since the `callback` option presumably only fires AFTER the content has been fully loaded.

Comment: Yes but I can load the content directly without Ajax if I go to the /contact.html page. If I am on the homepage can click the contact link then smoothState.js load it as Ajax. So the content get called both ways unfortunately. I could create a function and call it from both places?

Comment: @KeithPower, I cannot actually see what you're talking about.  I can only explain how it works and what you **must** do to make it work.  `.validate()` is the method of INITIALIZING the plugin.... it can only be called ONE time AFTER the form exists/loaded into the DOM.  It NEVER belongs inside of a `submit` handler.

Comment: @KeithPower, Can you let me know, how did you solve this? I'm facing a similar problem. Thanks

Comment: @PawanKumar, he probably solved it by following this answer.   If you have a problem, please post a new question rather than hijacking comments on an accepted answer.  Thanks.